# What does --frozen-intrinsics flag do in node.js?

Tags: node.js

The documentation for [`--frozen-intrinsics`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--frozen-intrinsics) says:

> Only the root context is supported. There is no guarantee that globalThis.Array is indeed the default intrinsic reference. Code may break under this flag

I couldn't understand this. Can someone help me understand this in simple words with an example?

Background: I was checking [nicolo-ribaudo/jest-light-runner](https://github.com/nicolo-ribaudo/jest-light-runner) where there is a mention of `--frozen-intrinsics`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `--frozen-intrinsics`, all the built-in JavaScript objects and functions are recursively frozen, except for `globalThis`.

If you run `node --frozen-intrinsics`, you can check it:

```js
> Object.isFrozen(Array)
true
> Object.isFrozen(Array.prototype)
true
> Object.isFrozen(globalThis);
false
> Array.isArray = () => true; Array.isArray(2); // you cannot modify built-in properties, this will not return true
false
> globalThis.foo = 3; foo; // you can still define new globals
3
> globalThis.Array = 4; Array; // However, you can also replace existing globals
4
```

This prevents your code from accidentally modifying globals, so I recommended it in `jest-light-runner` to prevent tests from accidentally influencing each other (since it doesn't isolate test files like Jest's default runner does).
Note that you still have a communication channel by attaching new properties to the global object, so it's not an isolation mechanism.

Now, lets take a look at the docs you quoted.

> Only the root context is supported.

In Node.js, you can create multiple "global contexts" using the vm built-in module. `--frozen-intrinsics` does not affect those contexts, so if you run node with `--frozen-intrinsics`:

```js
> Object.isFrozen(Array)
true
> Object.isFrozen(require("vm").runInNewContext("Array"))
false
```

> There is no guarantee that globalThis.Array is indeed the default intrinsic reference.

As mentioned earlier, `globalThis.Array` could still be replaced. However, if you have a "safe reference" to an object (either using syntax, or by storing the original `Array` global in a local variable), you can be sure that it's not modified:

```js
let OriginalArray = Array;

require("untrusted-module");

globalThis.Array; // this might have been replaces
[].push; // this is still the original one
OriginalArray.isArray; // this is still the original one
```

> Code may break under this flag

If code needs to modify built-ins, it would obviously stop working. For example, you cannot use polyfills that modify the global objects.